# How to correctly setup an Apache VirtualHost as HTTP and HTTPS?

Tags: virtualhost, centos6, httpd, httpd.conf, mod-ssl

I am trying to setup a locally (for development/testing purposes) SSL site using Apache and mod_ssl and this is what I have in my VirtualHost files:

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/local.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName reptool.dev

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magnific/reptooln_admin/web
    <Directory /var/www/html/magnific/reptooln_admin/web>
        # enable the .htaccess rewrites
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/reptool-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/reptool-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

/etc/httpd/conf.d/local-ssl.conf
<VirtualHost reptool.dev:443>
    ServerName reptool.dev:443

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magnific/reptooln_admin/web
    <Directory /var/www/html/magnific/reptooln_admin/web>
        # enable the .htaccess rewrites
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/reptool-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/reptool-access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key
</VirtualHost>
```

The first (the non-SSL) works just fine but with the SSL one I got not error 404:

```
The requested URL /app_dev.php was not found on this server.
```

Why? What I am missing at configuration level?

Answer (score 0):

Your ServerName "reptool.dev:443" doesn't look right to me, it should not have the port in it.  Try:

```
ServerName reptool.dev
```

Comment: Didn't work, still the same issue: 404 Not found

Comment: Try making a different log to see if requests are being picked-up by the HTTPS server:
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/reptool-access-https.log combined
Are you confident your ServerName matches your incoming requests?

Comment: Request are not beeing made to that URL I mean I can't see anything in logs, why?

Comment: Did you include your Listen and NameVirtualHost directives for port 443?
Listen 192.168.0.1:443
NameVirtualHost 192.168.0.1:443

Comment: I have in this way: `NameVirtualHost *:80 NameVirtualHost *:443` but that cause this error `Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443` during HTTPD restart